Will the Sram NX Eagle Dub Crankset fit the Sram Cassette 11-speed PG-113?
I would love your help and I'm hoping to learn about compatibility in the process. Will the Sram NX Eagle Dub Crankset fit the Sram Cassette 11-speed PG-113?


Thank you.

Is it just me, or does that (new?) chainring look more shark-finned than any used one I've ever seen?

@Michaelcomelately There is indeed an asymmetric tooth profile. Note that the teeth are larger than normal, so dimensionally it's all good even though they look worn.

I believe that the two components can physically be used together.
SRAM Transmission cranks and AXS road cranks (12s) use a different chain standard than the Eagle cranks. It's best to use SRAM's flat top chains with Transmission and AXS cranks. I believe that any 12s chain would work with Eagle MTB cranks. 11s chains should be OK also.
The PG-1130 cassette is an 11s cassette. It only goes down to an 11t small cog. If you pair that with an MTB crankset with a small chainring, your top speed is a bit limited. Also, some PG-1130 cassettes are designed for road double drivetrains (they have 32t or smaller big cogs), and you would probably not want to use those with a 1x drivetrain.
You'd want the 11-42 PG-1130 cassette on a 1x. Shimano's 11s GRX drivetrain was compatible with up to an 11-46, but that was also not as much range as SRAM's contemporary 12s drivetrains (10-44 or 10-52) had.
